# Dishwasher drain line goes from the bottom of the counter and up to the airgap...will this get clogged easily?

Tags: dishwasher

I'm concerned that the typical drain hose installation of my dishwasher is susceptible to food particles getting stuck (due to gravity) in the bottom part of the drain line between the dishwasher and the air gap.

To conserve water, people suggest that you just scrape off as much food as possible from the dishes so that you don't have to rinse your dishes before putting them into the dishwasher.

However, I'm afraid that little food particles will get through and get stuck in the drain somehow.

I see that inside the dishwasher tub, on the bottom. there is actually a couple of filters.  But I'm still concerned that bits may get through and eventually sit at the bottom of the hose.

Should I be concerned?  If so, then I guess I'm relegated to rinsing dishes before loading the dishwasher.

Comment: is the drain pipe attached to the same waste pipe as the sink? if it is, it has to be above the sink outlet.

Comment: anything that gets past the filters will be "whooshed" away by the pumped water pressure

Comment: @dandavis I hope so. I guess there shouldn't be anything heavy left on dishes before we run it. Thanks. That puts me a little bit more at ease.